# How to query to select all file in specific folder in android?

Tags: android, file

I want to get all files in a specific folder. Can anyone give me a suggestion how to query all files in a specific folder using manage query.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What do you need the files for?  Do you need the list of files?  Clarify your question.

Comment: You want all filenames from the folder or all files? Question is confusing, please ellaborate with some code if you have developed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way**

```
ArrayList<File> mFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
          File mDirectory;
         String folderPath = "/mnt/sdcard/download";
         mDirectory = new File(folderPath);
         ExtensionFilenameFilter filter = new ExtensionFilenameFilter(acceptedFileExtensions);

            // Get the files in the directory
            File[] files = mDirectory.listFiles(filter);
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                for (File f : files) {

                    mFiles.add(f);
                }

                Collections.sort(mFiles, new FileComparator());
            }
```